# Problem in my compositing tab

Tags: texturing, uv, compositing-nodes

My goal is to make a colored ribbon in Blender. I used an extruded bezier curve to model it, the use this short tutorial to put a flag color on it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9RDiG9a4Ao&ab_channel=CGMatter).

The problem is that when I link the image node on the map UV, the ribbon disappear and looks like that : [image: So what,s left of the ribbon is the blue part on the left]

Instead of that (with some colors of the flag on it): [image]

I used a Poliigon texture for the cloth texture, here is a picture of it (idk if it's useful) :
[image]

Here is a UV MAP screenshot :
[image]

Thanks a lot ! (I'm using blender 3.5)

Comment: I would recommend asking an actual question. It's not very clear what your goal is. I think the object may not have suitable UV map, but then, even if it did and you mapped the texture, you would have only the texture mapped and no shading from the render. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I'm sorry I'm pretty new to Blender 
I think it's clearer if you watch the tutorial that I put in the question. My goal is to project an image on the ribbon thanks to an image texture in the compositing tab. In the tutorial, the guy tell to use an UV map node to have some shadows but when I do that I have the problem on the first picture

Comment: If you are following a tutorial, the solution to any possible problem is most of the time to redo the tutorial and follow the instructions more closely. I recommend you do that. I don't think a lot of people here will want to spend their time watching the tutorial. If you want help, you have to ask clear, well formed questions. Even if I decide to watch it, there will be no way for me to know what you did differently to get to this problem, because most likely, the guy making this tutorial did not have the problem. Only you can find out, what you did wrong by redoing the tutorial.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. He wants to map the colors of the flag on the ribbon using compositing nodes, but when he tries it the ribbon disappears instead of getting the texture, so he's asking what's the right way to do it.
Unfortunately I don't know how to do this, and didn't even know it was possible. But the question is clear enough.

Comment: I watched the tutorial and you seem to be doing everything right in the compositing nodes. Please add a screenshot of the ribbon UV map.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati I add the UV map screen shot

Comment: So, the UVs are a bit weird. They are not contained all in the UV 1x1 space. I don't know if a texture in the compositor node automatically tiles or not, I guess it doesn't. I think the issue is your UV map. Do you understand how UV maps work and what they're for?

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati Yes I do know the basics of it

Comment: So, try unwrapping the UVs in a way that the whole ribbon UVs are contained in the 1x1 UV tile and are mapped the way you intend it to be.